# How to detect if someone broke a spruce log?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know it's possible to detect when players break certain blocks with the scoreboard criteria `stat.mineBlock`, but I was wondering how you detect if a player broke a block that has a data value, such as a particular type of wood?

I tried looking through the trusty tab key, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

`stat.mineBlock` by itself is a criteria, but you can also use an argument with it. For your example, try `stat.mineBlock.sapling`. However, these criteria cannot check metadata, so it would not be able to differentiate mining a spruce sapling from an oak one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SinglePlayer

When breaking a block, its pickUpDelay is 5. Test for items spawning with such pickUpDelay is enough.

```
testfor @e[type=Item,tag=!old] {Item:[...]}
```